# Голосовой набор текста

Tags: c#, microsoft-speech-sdk

Использую `Microsoft Speech`. Реализовал простой пример:

```
static TextBlock l;
SpeechRecognitionEngine speechEngine;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    tb1 = l;

    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-ru"); /* Язык распознования */
    speechEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(culture);
    speechEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); /* Откуда распозновать речь */

    speechEngine.SpeechRecognized += SpeechEngine_SpeechRecognized; /* Событие завершения распознования текста */

    Choices choices = new Choices(); /* Выбор распознования (комманды) */
    choices.Add(new string[] { "один два", "два", "три" });

    GrammarBuilder grammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
    grammarBuilder.Append(choices);
    Grammar grammar = new Grammar(grammarBuilder);
    speechEngine.LoadGrammar(grammar);

}

private void SpeechEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);
}
```

И как понял, распознает только слова указанные в `Choices`. Можно ли просто чтобы он не распознавал как команды и просто вводил текст?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже то что Вы хотите получить называется - `Dictation Mode`.

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("ru-ru");
var speechEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(culture);
speechEngine.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar()); // Dictation mode.
speechEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

speechEngine.SpeechRecognized += (sender, args) =>
{
    // Ваш обработчик.
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", args.Result.Words));
};
```

Но по своему опыту добавлю: что такое решение не является панацеей и процент ошибок может быть достаточно высок.

- [Детали на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Пример с MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Cannot find grammar referenced by this grammar."`, при добавлении словаря получаю ошибку. Получается его докачивать нужно?

Comment: @Идентикон, судя по всему у Вас подключена `Microsoft.Speech.dll`  попробуйте подключить `System.Speech.dll`.

Comment: C библиотекой `System.Speech.dll` вылетает на `CultureInfo`, с ошибкой мол такой ключ отсутствует. А Microsoft.Speech сделал похоже 
            `GrammarBuilder builder = new GrammarBuilder();
            builder.AppendDictation();`

Comment: @Идентикон, и с `builder.AppendDictation();` заработало? Ваш вопрос решен?

Comment: Нет, вылетает с ошибкой